# How to get this Java Layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

In an Java `BorderLayout` the `NORTH` part is normally like this:

[image]

So what I want to have is, that the `NORTH` and `SOUTH` part have the same width as the `CENTER`. But the `EAST` and `WEST` part should have the height of the `CENTER`. This means the corners should be empty. I don't want to use a `GridLayout` for this, because I don't want the `NORTH` to have the same height as the `CENTER`.

How do I get this layout?

Comment: Sounds more like a case for `GridBagLayout` or `GroupLayout` ..

Comment: Simply use two BorderLayout using JPanels. In the inner one, add your north and south panels. Place the inner one in the outer one's BorderLayout.CENTER position. Done.

Comment: In 199-2000 I used to make applets. I never saw need to use a layout manager. Do you want your layout to spring in and out? We used to setlayout(null) and set insets of each component ourselves, much better layout and works fine even today

Comment: example http://sel2in.com/pages/games/123/123_game.html u can decompile jar

Answer (score 5):

Simply nest two BorderLayout using JPanels. In the inner one, add your north and south panels. Place the inner one in the outer one's BorderLayout.CENTER position. Done.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleLayout extends JPanel {
   public SimpleLayout() {
      JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      innerPanel.add(createLabeledPanel("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      innerPanel.add(createLabeledPanel("North"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      innerPanel.add(createLabeledPanel("South"), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(createLabeledPanel("East"), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
      add(createLabeledPanel("West"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
   }

   private JComponent createLabeledPanel(String text) {
      JLabel label = new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.CENTER);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      panel.add(label);
      return panel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleLayout mainPanel = new SimpleLayout();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleLayout");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: @dma  *"But the `EAST` and `WEST` part should have the height of the `CENTER`."*  Or to put that another way, I think that means like [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30832022/418556).  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: ah, so much for careful reading, and thanks for the clarification. 1+ to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a comment, we can get this 'empty corners' layout quite easily using `GridBagLayout`.  The yellow parts are simply a (panel with a) label that has no text.

[image] [image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class EmptyCornerLayout {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    EmptyCornerLayout() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        gbc.weightx = 0.5;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        // first row
        addComponentToLayout(0, 0, 0d, 0d, Color.YELLOW, "");
        addComponentToLayout(0, 1, 1d, 0d, Color.CYAN, "NORTH");
        addComponentToLayout(0, 2, 0d, 0d, Color.YELLOW, "");

        // 2nd row
        addComponentToLayout(1, 0, 0d, 1d, Color.CYAN, "WEST");
        addComponentToLayout(1, 1, 1d, 1d, Color.RED, "CENTER");
        addComponentToLayout(1, 2, 0d, 1d, Color.CYAN, "EAST");

        // last row
        addComponentToLayout(2, 0, 0d, 0d, Color.YELLOW, "");
        addComponentToLayout(2, 1, 1d, 0d, Color.CYAN, "SOUTH");
        addComponentToLayout(2, 2, 0d, 0d, Color.YELLOW, "");
    }

    private final void addComponentToLayout(
            int row, int col, 
            double weightx, double weighty,
            Color color, String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);
        panel.add(new JLabel(text));

        gbc.gridx = col;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;
        ui.add(panel, gbc);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                EmptyCornerLayout o = new EmptyCornerLayout();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```